# I am having trouble with my if statement holding true even when it is

Tags: c++, arduino

My AltCheckInt Statement is not holding true. It works from 9999-33000 and then switches to false and again at 55000 it switches back to true and then to false again at 70000 for some unknown reason. the value of com is *SPEED 34482*. Anyone see anything I don't?

```
void AltDisplay(String com){

String AltCheckStg;
int AltCheckInt;
String Action;
String Status;
int StatusInt;
Action = com.substring(0,6);
if (Action == "SPEED "){
    Status = com.substring(6,10);
    AltCheckStg = com.substring(6,18);
    AltCheckInt = AltCheckStg.toInt();
    StatusInt = Status.toInt();
    Serial.println(AltCheckInt); 
    if(AltCheckInt >= 9999){
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      StatusInt = StatusInt/100;
    }
    s7s.write(0x77);
    s7s.write(0b0000001);
    s7s.print(StatusInt);
    delay(500);
    s7s.write(0x76);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use a *signed* int or an *unsigned int*?  When dealing with bits, `unsigned int` is highly recommended (the most significant bit usually determines whether the representation is negative or positive).

Comment: Looks like a good candidate to use with a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arduino is 16-bit, which means the largest value an [`int`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/int) can hold is 32,767. Due to [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), the next value you'll see after 32,767 is -32,768.

If you want a larger range, you might want to switch to [`long`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Long).

It is worth noting that `toInt()` already returns a `long`, so all you need to do is change the type of `AltCheckInt`.

Comment: That was it thank you. I was not thinking about it not being 32bit

Answer (score 0):

> AltCheckInt is an Integer , Which Consume 2 byte ( 16 bit)
>    Value Rang for integer is (+_2 power 15) = 32,767 to -32,768
>
> after crossing the limit it gives error,,,
>
> Change AltCheckInt to any big datatype Like : __int64 ,long long, unsigned long long
>
> Select datatype according to your requirement

[Table About Datatypes in C++ with Memory & Rang Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)

,